# Object creation strategy in domain driven design with repositories

Tags: c#, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I'm playing around with Domain Driven Development. I'm using a generic repository implementation that is defined as follows: (this is implemented as `Repository<T>`)

```
   public interface IRepository<T> where T : class, IEventSource, new()
    {
        T FindByKey(Guid key);
        IEnumerable<T> FindByQuery(Predicate<T> filter);
        IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
        T CreateObject();
    }
```

Let's say I have an Order class, that cannot be created without a Customer parameter. I'm using CreateObject to set the Key of the entity with a sequential Guid generator.

What is the solution that minimizes development time and coupling?

- Currently I have a parameterless constructor, and am calling some
  Initialize(Customer) method.
- I could create a ICustomerRepository, but that would mean there is a
  lot of extra development time  per entity.
- I can also modify CreateObject to take `params object[] args`, but that is not type safe at compile time.
- I could remove CreateObject and use constructors to create the object, but that means I need to have access to the the Guid generation algorithm everywhere I instantiate an object, increasing coupling.
- In a base class for an entity I could set the key in the constructor, reducing coupling, but requiring some static reference to the algorithm.

**Update**

I've implemented the strategy following sll's answer. The new signature for the repository is now:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class, IEventSource
{
    T FindByKey(Guid key);
    IEnumerable<T> FindByQuery(Func<T, bool> predicate);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    T CreateObject();
    T CreateObject(IConstructorParameters parameters);
}
```

The parameterless `CreateObject` creates an instance by attempting to call the parameterless constructor (using IL Emit for performance).

The second `CreateObject` attempts to create a method that calls the constructor where the properties on the `IConstructorParameters` match a constructor on the Entity object.

Implementation:

```
private Dictionary<Type, Func<IConstructorParameters, T>> _constructionMethods 
    = new Dictionary<Type, Func<IConstructorParameters, T>>();
public T CreateObject(IConstructorParameters args)
{
    T newObject;
    if (args == null)
    {
        args = ConstructorParameters.Empty;
    }
        Type paramType = args.GetType();
        Func<IConstructorParameters, T> constructor;

        if (!_constructionMethods.TryGetValue(paramType, out constructor))
        {
            //Emit IL to create a Func<IConstructorParameters,T>
            constructor = CreateConstructor(paramType);
            _constructionMethods.Add(paramType, constructor);
        }

        newObject = constructor(args);

    newObject.Key = _guidCreator.Generate();
    return newObject;
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason for putting the CreateObject() method in the repository, ie what's the benefit of having a generic method for creating objects?  In DDD I believe object creation would be the responsibility of a Factory rather than a Repository.  Typically a repository would have an Add method for adding an existing object to the store.

Comment: That is a good point, if I add this to a factory and would like to keep it generic, the same situation applies though.

Comment: @BasB you should think about stopping making everything generic, you can't make your object creation generic if you need some parameters, don't apply DRY too strictly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want implement `IOrderRepository` - you can abstract `CreateObject()` method parameters by an interface like `IConstructionParameters` and then for each entity implement concrete parameters like `OrderConstructionParameters`.

This approach also known as [Parameter Object](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ParameterObject) design pattern which design rationale - more [decoupled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decoupling#Software_Development) system design.

```
public interface IRepository<T> 
{
   T CreateObject(IConstructionParameters parameters);     
} 

public sealed class OrderConstructionParameters : IConstructionParameters
{
    public Customer Customer
    { 
       get; 
       private set; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a plan, going to check if I can create an IL emitter that creates objects based on this.

Answer (score 2):

Some points as suggestion, i would do as follows.

- Keep IRepository generic, and also create specific interfaces containing the contract only with what is relevant to the entity, ICustomerRepository as your example.
- Remove the guid generation to a service class, since this task is most relevant for the infrastructure and not domain.

Comment: I have the GUID generation in an interface IGuidGeneration, which is resolved using dependency injection.

Comment: It's ok, but mixing the infrastructure and domain, may not be as ideal, even with dependency injection.